# How to play a looping video in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer

How do I put an video clip in my storyboard? All I see is:

[image]

Also, where do I put the .mp4 file?

[image]

And last, what would be the correct code to include for a looping video clip when View Controller starts.

```
 //insert looping video clip here
```

I am familiar with Android Studio/java and can do this there no problem. However, I am very new to swift and Xcode so I am having trouble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make a looping Video :-

- Add a `UIView` to your ViewController, set constraints accordingly.
- Declare that `UIView` as `@IBOutlet` in your conforming class

  ```
      @IBOutlet weak var videoView : VideoPlay!
      //Where VideoPlay is a CustomClass for the Video player
  ```
- Create a custom Class for the video player `UIVew` : *`VideoPlay`*

  ```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation



  class VideoPlay: UIView {

       private var player : AVPlayer!

        private var playerLayer : AVPlayerLayer!

      init() {

               super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
                self.initializePlayerLayer()

            }

            override init(frame: CGRect) {
                super.init(frame: frame)
                self.initializePlayerLayer()
                self.autoresizesSubviews = false
            }

            required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
                super.init(coder: aDecoder)
                self.initializePlayerLayer()

            }


            private func initializePlayerLayer() {

                playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
                playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
                playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

                self.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                playerLayer.frame = self.bounds
            }

            func playVideoWithURL(url: NSURL) {

                player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
                player.muted = false

                playerLayer.player = player

                player.play()

                loopVideo(player)
            }

            func toggleMute() {
                player.muted = !player.muted
            }

            func isMuted() -> Bool
            {
                          return player.muted
            }

            func loopVideo(videoPlayer: AVPlayer) {

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { notification in

                    videoPlayer.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
                    videoPlayer.play()
                }
            }

        }
  ```
- Modify your StoryBoard conforming ViewController :-

  ```
     class ViewController: UIViewController {        

         @IBOutlet weak var videoView : VideoPlay!  

         override func viewDidLoad() {
                 super.viewDidLoad()
                         let bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
                         let moviePath: String = bundle.pathForResource("yourVideoFile_Name", ofType: "yourVideoFile_Type")!
                         let movieUrl : NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(moviePath)

                         videoView.playVideoWithURL(movieUrl)


             }....
       }
  ```
- Since the `videoView` conforms to class *`VideoPlay`* , You can access
  *`VideoPlay`*'s global function.

As for where to keep the video file , keep it in the main bundle i.e :- in your case *Fighting Trainer Pro* Folder

Such as :-

**`toggleMute()`**

**`isMuted()`**

Comment: Do I need to put the mp4 file anywhere? also, do I need to drag anything onto my storyboard?

Comment: just a looping video clip, I don't know what the difference between looping background video/and looping video is.

Comment: Absolutely no difference but the possibility of adding other subviews on the videoPlayer, Thats all...I have updated my answer :)

Comment: Where exactly do I reference the video file in my code?

Comment: In the class function `viewDidLoad()` of the viewController class that is conforming to the storyboard viewcontroller. I have mentioned it in my answer...

Comment: Apple provided some sample code (AVPlayerLooper) during the WWDC 2016 session called Advances in AVFoundation Playback. They discuss the optimal way to loop a video using an `AVQueuePlayer`

Slide 59: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/503lkp4vimgv7tqecn7/503/503_advances_in_avfoundation_playback.pdf
Sample Code: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

An Objective-C version of Dravidian's answer. Also contains the crucial `layoutSubviews` method, so that the video layer actually stays the same size as the view!

```c
#import "LBVideoView.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface LBVideoView ()
{
    AVPlayer *_player;
    AVPlayerLayer *_playerLayer;
}
@end

@implementation LBVideoView
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return [[super initWithFrame:frame] commonInit];
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    return [[super initWithCoder:aDecoder] commonInit];
}

- (instancetype)commonInit
{
    _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer new];
    _playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor.CGColor;
    _playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    [self.layer addSublayer:_playerLayer];
    _playerLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)playVideoWithURL:(NSURL*)url
{
    _player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
    _playerLayer.player = _player;
    [_player play];
    [self loopVideo];
}

- (void)loopVideo
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieEnded) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];
}
- (void)movieEnded
{
    [_player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [_player play];
}

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    _playerLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end
```